How do I use GoogleSignInClient correctly?
I'm trying to implement GoogleSignInClient in my Android application. My goal is to obtain a GoogleSignInAccount so that I can use it with another service (Fitness API).
I've been working on this for days, following all of the documentation and examples I can find. My app has all the dependencies. I went to Google Cloud Console and set up a project. I imported the SHA hash of my development certificate. I set up the OAuth consent screen. I created an OAuth 2.0 client ID. In fact I created two of them, one of type Android and one of type Web, because several bits of documentation that I read insist you need the Web version even for an app.
When I configure and start the sign in intent, I do get a list of accounts. I pick one (the same one I added as a test user in the OAuth consent screen). The first time through, I received a couple more screens asking me for consent, although I don't get those anymore.
The bottom line is, every time I get to the point in the code where I should be getting the GoogleSignInAccount (in the onActivityResult method) it throws an exception. The exception is always "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10" which means DEVELOPER ERROR. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.
The example I started with is this -
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Configure Google Sign-In
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail() // Request email address as basic profile
            .build()

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        // Check if user is already signed in
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        if (account != null) {
            // User is signed in, proceed accordingly
            // For example, you can update UI, navigate to another activity, etc.
        } else {
            // User is signed out, show the sign-in button
            // You may want to show a sign-in button to the user
        }
    }

    // Triggered when the sign-in button is clicked
    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

   // Handle the result of the sign-in activity
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign-In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                // You can now use the GoogleSignInAccount to authenticate with Firebase
                // For example, you can get the user's email address:
                val email = account?.email
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign-In failed, update UI accordingly
            }
        }
    }

In my case, I'm also including a requestIdToken with the GoogleSignInOptions and I'm also requesting Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read"), although I've tried it without either or both of those too. The exception is thrown from the line that says "val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)".
Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.
